# Unable to extract values from XML query results

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2019, nodes, extract

I've seen and tried so many possible solutions to extracting values from this XML, seems one of them should work but can't seem to get any data from this.  Can I possibly get some direction on how to extract some values (MANUF_ID would be great).  XML is below, using VS 2019, VB.NET. I have verified that the XML has been loaded into an XML Document (XmlDocument) reviewing inner/outer xml - inner XML shown below that has been returned from a query via a Web Service.  Any help would be much appreciated.

The # of records can run into several hundred-thousand once in production that I will need to extract data values for several fields and load into a database table as-is (the ultimate goal).

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    -<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header/>
    -<env:Body>
    -<m:cpwwsgenericexportResponse xmlns:m="http://www.deltek.com/enterprise/integration/ws/cpwwsgenericmodule">
    <m:String><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
    <pdmmanuf_qry xmlns='http://www.deltek.com/enterprise/integration/pdmmanuf_qry'> 
    <PDMMANUF_MANUF> 
      <MANUF_ID>ACE</MANUF_ID> 
      <MANUF_NAME>ACE ELECTRO-MECHANICALS</MANUF_NAME> 
    </PDMMANUF_MANUF> 
    <PDMMANUF_MANUF> 
      <CAGE_ID_FLD>54321</CAGE_ID_FLD>
      <MANUF_ID>JIMSTEST3</MANUF_ID> 
      <MANUF_NAME>Jims Test Manuf 3</MANUF_NAME>
    </PDMMANUF_MANUF> </pdmmanuf_qry> </m:String>
    </m:cpwwsgenericexportResponse>
    </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
```

I've tried SelectNodes and GetElementsByTagName with just about every combination of addresses I could think of or found in my searches including this and removing each level with and without all the slashes, and the same prefixing w/a "." (dot).

```
SelectNodes("cpwwsgenericexportResponse/pdmmanuf_qry/PDMMANUF_MANUF/MANUF_ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is the Xml namespace. Try use `System.Xml.Linq` that use `XNamespace`

For example; you have a namespase like that

```
Public loc As XNamespace = "urn:www.pippo:v1"
```

For reading you can use linq like this

```
Dim strXml = (From f In doc.Descendants(loc + "MyXmlTree") 
                      Select New myClsDto With {.myPropInDto = f.Element(loc + "myXmlChild").GetXmlElement}).FirstOrDefault
```